# Zoom effect in mobile application only in required area?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I've a problem in my application. Native browser zoom in mobile devices don't fit my needs...
I've 3 main parts in my mobile web page.

1. Header
2. Main content area (there will be scroll inside this if content will increase)
3. Footer

If i use native zoom of mobile browsers then my whole page gets zoomed..
but i don't wants zoom effect in header and footer..
What i wants is to implement native browser zoom effect only in content area..

So please give me some guideline how it is possible to achieve this without any errors or cross browser issues?